# Illustrator Advanced Clipping Mask with Text

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography

I'm trying to create a clipping mask where my text takes on the colors of the picture underneath it. This is the desired effect:

[image: desired effect]

I have been able to create a regular clipping mask [as seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8nhd.png), but the text around the image disappears and gets cut off (also inside, in the white areas). Instead, I would like it these areas to be grey and not disappear.

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want is an **Opacity mask** not a clipping mask.

Select all and click the **Make Mask** button on the **Transparency Panel**, you may then need to click the invert or clip options on the panel as well.